# Magento Print Packing slip before shipping

Tags: magento

How can I print a packing slip before the order status is "complete" (i.e. before I submit a shipment?)
The current workflow is a bit backwards, especially if you are using the packing slip as a pick list in the warehouse.

Extra: A solution that is upgrade friendly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/automatic_picklist_printing_with_check_for_order_payment

Get a paid for module if time is money, otherwise muddle through the above link or write your own module. Observe order creation and send an email of the order may be one way to go if you want it customised with attributes not on the normal order email. Otherwise, cc new orders to an account, print them out and take them down the warehouse.

Comment: I was looking for the place to do this in code so 
a) I can learn to write magento extensions, with a trivial example b) I can offer this in the magentoconnect community since Lots of people asked about this functionality.

Comment: What I wanted was a Windows app that checked for new orders and printed out a picking list automatically, using the least amount of paper possible, grouping items irrespective of order id so that only one trawl of the stockroom is needed. This could then sit on the warehouse PC and remove the need to log in and check stuff. Failing that, a Magento program could do the same, generating a PDF with the Zend library with a simple dashboard button that only shows if there are items needing to be picked. With a free extension you should get paid for work customising it for people.

Comment: That link is now broken. Thanks a lot Magento. >:-(

Comment: Here's what I do now to print the packing slip and put it in the shipping envelope or box, BEFORE shipping:

  a. Website Admin panel ->

  b. Orders ->

  c. open the order -> 

  d. Invoices tab -> 

  e. Select invoice ->

  f. Click "Print" button ->

  g. Save PDF file.

  h. Print PDF and put in shipping envelope or box.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent hours searching the internet for a solution to this problem and finally used

'[Print Packingslips (pre shipped)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/print-packing-slips-pre-shipped.html)'.

It prints your packingslips/pick lists with any order status. Works perfectly and is the cheapest module I can find.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/print-packing-slips-pre-shipped.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that does the same thing, slightly cheaper:

http://www.reddotdevelopment.com/store/magento-order-picklist-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't bothered to purchase any of these extensions to see how they've implemented the ability to print before shipping, but I've been able to do it myself pretty easily.

Seems there just isn't Admin UI around all of them, but it turns out there are a numerous models that support a `getPdf` method.

- Creditmemo
- Invoice
- Shipment
- Packaging

The difference between calling `getPdf` on `Invoice` instead of `Shipment` is there is no tracking info on the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need third party add-ons for this. You can just click "Submit Shipment" before you have actually packed it and you will be OK.

You can then print the packing slip, pack it up and actually ship it.

Then you can add the tracking number and send the customer email afterwards by clicking the "Send Tracking Information" button.

That's how I do it.